# match the last element with javscript regex without starting with greedy

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to resolve the following scenario with javascript regexp:

I have the following text:

```
<foo>a</foo>blah <bar>blah</bar><abc>dsdfsdf</abc> blah<foo>b</foo><blah></blah>{COMPANY_NAME}
```

I would like to catch the `{COMPANY_NAME}` with text inside the previous foo tag.

so here i'm trying to find the text `b` that exists inside the first foo tag behind the COMPANY_NAME.

the only way i found to do that is to start with a greedy character, which means to use this:

```
/.*<foo>(.*?)<\/foo>.*?{COMPANY_NAME}/
```

if I don't start with the greedy selection at the begginging (`.*`) then it will provide the first foo instead of the last one, the problem is that this document is really big and it takes a lot of memory and it takes a long time to return each match and i'mm doing a lot of matches.

is there a way to resolve it without starting with the greedy `.*`? and just to return the last foo properly so the match will only contain what i need and not more then that ?

thanks

Comment: Is regex your only option? Using `.*` and `.*?` can cross matching the tags to get to `{COMPANY_NAME}`  and also using multiple occurrences can easily stretch to get matches that you don't want. Perhaps using a DOM parser is a more robust approach.

Comment: @Thefourthbird - yeah dom parser looks like the best approach.. still wondering if regex can handle that

Comment: Perhaps positive lookbehind is useful like `yourStr.match(/(?<=.)<foo>(.*?)<\/foo>.*?{COMPANY_NAME}/)`

Comment: @ufk If have have that string format, a regex can handle it using the given answer by anubhava.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex without initial greedy `.*`:

```sh
<foo>((?:(?!<\/?foo>).)*?)<\/foo>(?:(?!<\/?foo>).)*?{COMPANY_NAME}
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/J5JJSG/1)

Here `(?:(?!<\/?foo>).)*?` is tempered greedy pattern that matches zero or more characters where each character must not be followed by `<foo>` or `</foo>`.

Comment: Nitpicks: *"matches one or more"* should be: *"matches zero or more"*. *"where each character must not be followed by"* should be something like: *"where each character is not the first character of"*.